# Codepen using react-resizable-panels react component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, codepen

I'm trying to set up a codepen using this react component:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-resizable-panels

Althought the codepen isn't generating any errors, nothing is being rendered. Here's a link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/opike99/pen/LYXVRvL

To confirm that the rest of the code works, I set up the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    // This doesn't work
    return <ClientComponent />;
    // This works
    // return <div>This is some text.</div>
  }
}
```

and if you comment and uncomment the appropriate lines, the simple text does get rendered.

Update: Although the codepen console doesn't show any errors, the developer tools console shows the following error:

> react.js:185 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit
> https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full
> message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and
> additional helpful warnings.

I'm wondering if the issue has to do with multiple versions of React. Although React 18.20.0 has been specified in the settings of the codepen, it's odd that the stack trace shows the error coming from React 17.0.1:
[image]